# three dots menu of some sort windows sqlite3

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlite, atom-editor

When I try ls -1 (in powershell) to try and get into my table and check it, I get some sort of menu "...>" that I can't .quit out of. when I close out and run sqlite3 -init ex1.sql ex1.db (my example I'm working with, I get " Error: near line 1: table person already exists " when it in fact, does not. how do I get out of this menu, and how do I fix my code? Also, what IS this menu?

---

My sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`...>` is shown by the `sqlite3` command-line shell (not PowerShell) when you have not finished the current SQL command. Typically, you forgot the terminating `;`, or you forgot a `'` and are still inside a string.

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't tell *what* was going on or why the application seemed to have become unresponsive!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't specify what is the database in which you are working. For example before creating the table, use `.open <name_database.db>` and after run you `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Also the 3 dots `...>` means that you didn't write the complete command, most often you didn't put the semicolon `;` or you didn't close well the `'`. You can exit from this menu by killing the process or complete the command.